# Javascript audio giving "The element has no supported sources" error on play

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, game-development

I'm making my first javascript game (Snake), and I've already finished most of it. Now I'm trying to add sound, but it's not working. I'm not using a server, I'm using a local html file.

This is the constructor method of the class where I'm trying to play a sound:

```
constructor(){
    ...
    this.collect_wav = new Audio("Sounds\\Coin.wav");
    ...
}
```

And later in one of the methods:

```
relocate(){
    ...
    this.collect_wav.play();
}
```

When the code runs, the `new Audio` runs without an error, but on the line `play()`, I get this error in the developer console:
[image: The error I get]
There is a "Sounds" folder in the same directory as my html file, and inside that folder is `Coin.wav`, so I think the path is correct, but it just doesn't work. But when I go into the developer console, and go to the `sources` tab, I don't even see the `Sounds` folder listed, only the html, css, and javascript files are there:
[image: Files]

I have tried using the html tag like this:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="Sounds/Coin.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

Even this doesn't work, I see the controls show up, but it is greyed out and cannot be interacted with:

[image: Greyed out controls]

I have also tried replacing the backslashes with a normal slash (Because I'm not sure which one is correct in html), but this also didn't help. I have been trying to fix this for days, and I really have no idea what's wrong.

Edit: I've found the problem, it's something wrong with the wav file I'm using, when I changed it to a random wav file I downloaded from the internet, it worked. Then it stops working when I change it back to the original wav. So I guess it's just something wrong with the wav file I'm using.

Comment: I think you're just getting messed up by the path...you can try `src="./Sounds/Coin/wav` if the Sounds directory is in the same directory as your javascript file

Comment: @DaveVanFleet I tried your suggestion, but it's still not working.

Comment: Are you running a local server or just opening up the html file with the browser by double clicking on it?

Comment: @JonasGrumann No, I'm not using a server. I'm just opening the html file with the browser.

Comment: I think the issue is something along the lines of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037756/audio-not-loading-in-htmls-audio-tag I would suggest running a local webserver which is usually the way to go anyway, by opening the file in the browser you'll find all kind of issues

Comment: Ok, I'll try using a local server.